# Properties on proximal term

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

If the equation $x_i$-subproblem showed below is not strictly convex

$\arg \min_{x_i}=f_i(x_i)+\frac{\rho}{2}\|A_ix_i+\sum_{j\neq i}A_jx_j^k-c-\frac{\lambda^k}{\rho}\|_2^2$

Why adding the proximal term $\frac{1}{2}\|x_i-x_i^k\|^2_{P_i}$ showed below can make the subproblem strictly or strongly convex?

$arg \min_{x_i} f_i(x_i)+\frac{\rho}{2}\|A_ix_i+\sum_{j\neq i}A_jx_j^k-c-\frac{\lambda^k}{\rho}\|_2^2+\frac{1}{2}\|x_i-x_i^k\|^2_{P_i}$

Comment: Possible typo in your formula. Did you mean $x_i - x_j$ ?

Comment: sorry for wrong typing, make corrections $\frac{1}{2}\|x_i-x_i^k\|^2_{P_i}
$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of a convex function and a strongly convex function is again strongly-convex. This is a direct application of the definition of [strong-convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions).

On the other hand, it should be clear that $u \mapsto u^TP_iu$ is strongly convex if $P_i$ is positive definite.

Comment: but the term $\frac{\rho}{2}\|A_ix_i+\sum_{j\neq i}A_jx_j^k-c-\frac{\lambda^k}{\rho}\|_2^2$ is strongly convex, why add another strongly convex term $\frac{1}{2}\|x_i-x_i^k\|^2_{P_i}$ in this updating formulation?

Comment: That term is strongly-convex iff $A_i^TA_i$ is positive definite (i.e iff $A_i$ has full rank). Is this the case ? If so, then add it as a hypothesis in you question. Please take some time to write down your  problem / question as neatly and completely as you can. Or maybe you could provide a link to the paper you're trying to understand ?

Comment: I don't know that what is the difference between "penalty term" in equation(2.6) in https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf
and "proximal term" in Algorithm 4 in
ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam13-64.pdf

why the penalty term can be shown to be differentiable under rather mild conditions on the original problem and proximal term can make the subproblem strictly or strongly convex?

Comment: OK, it appears the authors use language which is not very rigorous. They say in the introduction that the $A_i$ have full column-rank. Thus by virtue of my comments above, the $x_i$ sub-problem is already strongly convex. However, $A_i^TA_i$ may be very ill-conditioned (i.e the smallest eigenvalue of $A_i^TA_i$ though strictly positive, may be terribly smaller than the largest).  A judicious choice for the $P_i$'s may then repair this ill-conditioning.

Comment: Sorry for another question, I don't clearly know the explanation of meaning in "penalty term" in equation(2.6) in https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf
why this term can be shown to be differentiable under rather mild conditions on the original problem.

Comment: For the "mild conditions", you can take the Assumptions 1 & 2 of this manuscript http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~angelia/note_solving_dual.pdf. The differentiability of the dual function is then the object of Lemma 1 of the same manuscript. The main idea at play here is the so-called Danskin's Theorem.